# How do I make navbar links not warp on close using CSS?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have a problem that when I close my side navbar the links warp to the size of the navbar. I want the links (circled in pink in the image below) to remain the same size and not warp. Is there a way to do this with CSS? Thank you!

Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/toshvelaga/pen/OJymXxO

Here is the CSS for the navbar and navbar links:

```
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 1.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

Here is the JS that makes the navbar width change:

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "350px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

[image]

Comment: So you want it to stay small? Or stay big?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most specific way to do this is using `white-space: nowrap` on the links. This is preferred, so you don't need to use hard-coded numbers like `300px`.

```css
.sidenav a {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Demo

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "350px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 1.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 120px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About the Site</a>
  <a href="#">Service Terms</a>
  <a href="#">All Our Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact Us for More Information</a>
</div>

<h2>How do I make the sidenav links not decrease in size when the sidenav closes?</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
```

Comment: Fair enough. I forgot about white-space. Just wasn't sure if jQuery adjusted width that it'd apply to that as well. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

****EDIT**** The better way to do it (per Andy) is to just use `white-space: nowrap;` I thought a JS adjustment of width would mess with it, but I was wrong. I'd change it to that instead. :)

Just add `min-width: 300px;` to your .side-bar a CSS

Here is the codepen that works. :)

[The codepen](https://codepen.io/jrhager84/pen/gOaWMQo)

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: Also - If it answered your question, please mark it 'answered' so that it may help people in the future. Thanks!

Comment: I will, SO won't let you mark it 'answered' until 4 minutes after a response is left :)

Comment: I see. No worries! Glad to be of help! :)